# Unable to resolve held broken packages while re-installing nginx - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nginx

[image: console errors]

How can I get rid of unmet deps and install?

What the console reads when I type 'apt-cache policy nginx libpcre3':`

```
Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.7
  Version table:
     1.4.6-1ubuntu3.7 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.4.6-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libpcre3:
  Installed: 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.3
  Candidate: 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.3
  Version table:
 *** 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:8.31-2ubuntu2.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:8.31-2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

`

Comment: Copy-paste terminal output into your question, don't use screenshots.  As for the unmet dependencies, are you using nginx from the getdeb repositories?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do that - I'm  just getting to know this part of SE. And yes, I've tried both source files from nginx.org and via a wget after adding deb sources to /etc/apt/sources.list, both without success. Is there a preferred method?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy nginx libpcre3`?

Comment: @ Thomas Ward : I hope I did what you were after- I typed out 'apt-cache policy nginx libpcre3' and got the output as pasted into the blockquote above. As you might have known I'm a windows user and only getting acquainted with Linux. (Ubuntu Studio 14.04 'Trusty Tahr', if it matters).

Comment: @ Thomas Ward: *whereis nginx* returns *nginx: /etc/nginx*  - if that means something specific is wrong.

Comment: Well, what was the answer?